# CentOS7へのWeblogic 12インストーラで真っ白なインストーラ画面しか表示されない

Tags: java, centos, oracle, weblogic

Cent OS 7をクリーンインストール後にWeblogic 12.2.1.4をセットアップしようとしています。
Oracleサイトから
・jdk-8u311-linux-x64.rpm
・fmw_12.2.1.4.0_wls_lite_Disk1_1of1.zip
をダウンロードしてJDKのインストールに成功したのでWeblogic Serverをインストールしようとしましたが
添付画像の通り、真っ白な画面が出てしまい継続できません。
Webも調べたのですが該当情報がなく、回避策をご存じの方はいらっしゃいませんか。
(Windows 10のPCで同じ手順をした場合は正常なインストーラが表示されました)

```bash
[xxxxx@xxxxxxx Downloads]$ java -jar ./fmw_12.2.1.4.0_wls_lite_generic.jar 
Launcher log file is /tmp/OraInstall2022-03-10_05-32-07PM/launcher2022-03-10_05-32-07PM.log.
Extracting the installer . . . . Done
Checking if CPU speed is above 300 MHz.   Actual 3499.896 MHz    Passed
Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors.   Actual 4294967296    Passed
Checking swap space: must be greater than 512 MB.   Actual 3967 MB    Passed
Checking if this platform requires a 64-bit JVM.   Actual 64    Passed (64-bit not required)
Checking temp space: must be greater than 300 MB.   Actual 38876 MB    Passed
Preparing to launch the Oracle Universal Installer from /tmp/OraInstall2022-03-10_05-32-07PM
```

[image: Java画面]

Comment: JAVA_HOMEは設定されています。 
[xxxxxxx@xxxxxx Downloads]$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_311-amd64

Comment: JDK をインストールしていますが、元々 OS に別バージョンの Java が入っておりそちらを参照している可能性もあります。まずは `java -version` または `java --version` 
(ハイフンが1つまたは2つ) で意図したバージョンが参照されているか確認してみると良いかもしれません。

Comment: @cubick 
アドバイスありがとうございます。
最初はOpenJDKが入っていた（下記）のでこれらは削除する必要が確かにありました。java -versionについては確認していますが問題なさそうでした。

[xxxx@xxxx ~]$ sudo yum list installed | grep java
java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64                   1:1.7.0.261-2.6.22.2.el7_8 
java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless.x86_64          1:1.7.0.261-2.6.22.2.el7_8
java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64                   1:1.8.0.322.b06-1.el7_9   
java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless.x86_64          1:1.8.0.322.b06-1.el7_9

Comment: 自己レスですが、XRDP経由では上記の事象が継続するものの、Hyper-V上のCentOSに直接画面接続して同じ操作をするとインストーラが正常に表示されます・・・。理由がよくわかりませんのでもう少し調べてまた何かわかったら自己レスします。